# How to combine rows based on id and sum a specific field

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am trying to combine rows that has similar identification. My table looks like this:

[image: Table]

I want to fill either Debit or Credit if the value is `'0.00'` from another row with the same Source and then perform a `Debit - Credit` calculation, like this:

```
+------------+----------+---------+----------+----------+-------+
|Source      | Property | ID      | Debit    | Credit   |Balance|
+------------+----------+---------+----------+----------+-------+
|HOCV1900091 | PROP0003 | 1.01.86 | 16800.00 | 16800.00 | 0.00  |
+------------+----------+---------+----------+----------+-------+
```

How to it ?

I did:

```
SELECT 
    a.[Date],
    a.[Source],
    a.[Property],
    a.[ID],
    [Debit] = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT  Debit FROM #ProcSubLegder b WHERE b.Source = a.Source FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,''),
    [Credit] = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT  Credit FROM #ProcSubLegder b WHERE b.Source = a.Source FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,''),
    a.[Balance]
FROM #ProcSubLegder a
GROUP BY [Date],[Source],[Property],[ID],[Credit],[Balance]
```

But it gives me a very terrible result.

Answer (score 0):

You should be aggregating only by the source and property:

```
SELECT
    Source,
    Property,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ID LIKE '%[0-9].[0-9]%' THEN ID END) AS ID,
    MAX(Debit) AS Debit,
    MAX(Credit) AS Credit,
    MAX(Credit) - MAX(Debit) AS Balance
FROM #ProcSubLegder
GROUP BY
    Source,
    Property;
```

Note: This answer assumes that each source/property group would have at most two records' worth of transactions.  If not, the above answer would have to change, and you should show the actual data.

Comment: Thanks, Let say I have 5 or more transactions ?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Can you add sample data which explains this new requirement?

Comment: You stated that your answer assumes that each source/property would have at most two records' worth of transactions. let say i have more than two records worth of transaction ?

Comment: I suggest that you open a new question.  We need to see the actual updated data.